# My Lg P500 will not connect to internet servers

Tags: internet, lg-optimus-one

I was using my LG P500 perfectly fine on the internet when all of a sudden a messaged flashed up on the screen internet disconnected.

So I went into settings to my `wireless & network` settings and turned off my WiFi, then turned it on again then went into WiFi settings. When I went into here there were no known networks showing up and the scanning wheel was just going round and round.  So I thought since I know the pass word, I will just add a new network. Then after this on the screen popped up another message saying `unable to scan for networks`.

Then my WiFi turned off on my phone. So I rebooted my phone and again this is still happening. It is not just at my house but everywhere I go I cannot connect to networks. :(

Please help I am a person whom needs Internet !

Comment: Did you maybe install something new shortly before "all of a sudden" all the above happened? Just asking whether maybe some malware is involved, as what you describe sounds strange. If not, and nobody else has a better idea: Make a full backup and then a factory-reset might be your last ressort. If that doesn't help either, your WiFi hardware has gone nuts, and you would need to turn-in your device to service.

Comment: Try to enable 3G/GPRS data and enable `Portable Wi-Fi hotspot`. Give a unique name and password and try to access this network from other WiFi enabled device. If you could get access, then you can rest assured that your WiFi hardware is okay.

Comment: Thanks guys for the ideas , i tried both but i had to factory reset it :L